A movie about two separated brothers that when re-united cause havoc
Seen this around 2006, Color, English.
It is about two brothers with some super natural powers or something like that. They lived their whole lives separate from each other, until one day they meet. And somehow the knew that they are brothers.
At the same time they are together, crimes are happening, (it is later revealed that these crimes happened because these two brothers united).
I remember the elder brother was very good at chess, and that he was playing against two men.. Later these two men stop at a toilet and one of them is killed, the other is lured inside and then killed, too.
The last scene ends abruptly with the younger brother laying on a bed, a doctor (or psychiatrist) approaches him and tries to seduce him? I couldn't understand the ending.

Seems you're after Headspace from 2005. From IMDb:

Headspace is about two brothers whose close proximity to each other causes evil to rise in those around them. Some trick of nature lets them use more of their brains than others do and that seems to cause the manifestations of evil. They get headaches often and don't function very well in society. After their mother goes wacky and is shot by the father, the father gives the boys up for adoption, telling the authorities not to place them together in any foster home. They spend years apart and don't even know each other when the[y] come together.

The protagonist is obsessed with chess and people around him start dying. Here's the trailer:



